# Подмена текста в скриптах на значение указанное в параметре запускаемого .bat файла

Tags: sql, windows, oracle, bat

Как можно реализовать подмену текста в скриптах myscript.sql и export.sql значением параметра при вызове run.bat?

Желаемый вариант запуска скрипта с параметром: `run.bat 2010`.

В текущей реализации, при запуске не происходит подмены внутри выполняемых скриптов `@C:\Scripts\myscript.sql` и `@C:\Scripts\export.sql`.

Текст run.bat:

```
call C:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sql.exe user/password@db @C:\Scripts\myscript.sql
```

Текст myscript.sql:

```
set embedded on
set pagesize 0
set echo off
set feedback on
set linesize 32767 
set headsep off
set verify off
set termout off
set newpage none
set termout off
set format off
set tab off
set wrap off
set underline off
set trimspool off
set trimout on 
set sqlformat csv ;;;

spool ./Export/export_data_%1.csv;

@C:\Scripts\export.sql;

spool off;
set headsep on;
set termout on;
exit;
```

Текст из файла export.sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE year = %1;
```

Comment: Уйдите от .BAT в более вменяемый скриптовый формат (ну хотя бы VBS), там читайте свои файлы, выполняйте подмены, сохраняйте их во временные файлы и передавайте серверу на обработку, после чего удаляйте.

Comment: Согласен с тобой, но сейчас нужно решение на базе батника

Comment: Батник или не батник - но в любом разе для замены надо копировать исходный файл в другой с выполнением при копировании этой замены.

Comment: Меняйте перлом, если на сервере, то он уже установлен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как можно реализовать подмену текста

Как ни странно, переменными *замещения* (=*подмены*), см. `SQL> help define`.
Для параметров SQL скрипта это: `&1,&2..&n`.

Содержание скриптов для задачи как в вопросе:

```
H:\> type run.bat  myscript.sql export.sql
run.bat

set SQLCL=D:\app\oracle\sqlcl\bin\sql.exe
call %SQLCL% db/db@mpsrv/pdb1.19c @myscript.sql %1

myscript.sql

define year=&1
@export.sql &year;

export.sql

define year=&1
set verify off termout off
set sqlformat csv ;;;
spool export_&year..csv
select *
from mytable where year='&year';
spool off
exit
```

Желаемый вариант запуска скрипта, даст ожидаемый результат:

```
H:\> run.bat 2010 > nul

H:\> type export_2010.csv
"ID";"YEAR"
1;"2010"
2;"2010"
3;"2010"
```